# jQuery closest() behaving differently in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

**What I want to achieve**

I have a button and some canvas elements on my page and when I click on that button or on a canvas element an overlay div (`#add-elements`) will slide in. When I click somewhere else (that is not on the overlay div, not the button and not the canvas element) the overlay div will disappear. With Firefox and IE the solution with jQuery's `closest()` works fine:

```
if (!$(event.target).closest('#add-elements').length
    && !$(event.target).closest('#show-button-wrapper').length
    && !$(event.target).closest('.gui-element').length) {
    hideEditPanel(); // this hides the overlay div
}
```

**The acutal problem**

But when in Chrome, `hideEditPanel()` gets called even when I click the button. I made some console outputs and `!$(event.target).closest('#show-button-wrapper').length` is `true` in Chrome but `false` in Firefox and IE.

**My DOM structure**

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="page">
            <div id="main">
                <div id="content">
                    <div id="add-elements">
                    </div>
                    <div id="show-button-wrapper">
                        <button id="show-button">show panel</button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="bigcanvas">
                        <canvas id="first" class="gui-element"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- #content -->
            </div> <!-- #main -->
        </div> <!-- #page -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**

`event.target` is `<span class="ui-button-text">` in Chrome and the button element itself in Firefox. When I click on the edge of the button in Chrome (forcing the target to be the button element, not the span inside) it seems to work.

Comment: Why use closest on an ID. IDs must be unique. Please click the `<>` button in the editor and post a [mvce]

Comment: directly access ID it is faster and no complication

Comment: How would you check if one of the parent elements of the clicked one has a certain ID?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this approach works for you:

```js
$(document.body).on('click', function(e){
  var t = $(e.target).closest('#content');
  if (!t.length) {
    $('#add-elements').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="page" style="border:3px solid #000">page
            <div id="main" style="border:3px solid #f00">main
                <div id="content" style="border:3px solid #0f0">content
                    <div id="add-elements" style="border:3px solid #00f">add-elements
                    </div>
                    <div id="show-button-wrapper" style="border:3px solid #888">
                        <button id="show-button">show panel</button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="bigcanvas" style="border:3px solid #f0f">bigcanvas
                        <canvas id="first" class="gui-element"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- #content -->
            </div> <!-- #main -->
        </div> <!-- #page -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I understand it right your code is hiding the `#add-elements` div if the click happened outside `#content`. But that is not exactely what I intended to do. I want to hide the `#add-elements` div if the click happens on an element that is neither the button, nor the div, nor a `canvas.gui-element` (I have several, but to simplify the code snippet I left out the others)

Comment: PS: `$(e.target).closest('#content')` should be identical to `$('#content')`

Comment: @elementzero23 I assumed that <div id="content"> only has content you don't want to react to the click. So a click outside is the same as a not clicking any content like the canvas, button and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may mean:

```
$("#content").on("click",function(e)  {
  if (["div","canvas"].indexOf(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase()) ==-1) {
    hideEditPanel(); 
  }
});
```